# Cant connect Redshift target for DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration

I want to migrate data from RDS to Redshift. For this, i want to use AWS DMS. I successfully connect RDS instance (postgres) like source, but i have issue with Redshift like target.

I filled connection data (username, password, port, servername: redshift_endpoint:5439:db_name). But i have an error:

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: 
Cannot connect to Cloud server  Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message:
 RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08S01 NativeError: 10
 Message: [unixODBC][Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (10) Error occurred while 
trying to connect: [SQLState 08S01] could not translate host name 
"some_path.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439" to address: Name or service not 
known   ODBC general error.
```

Whats I do wrong?

Comment: First thing to check is security groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this same problem for some time today. I found that you don't need to add the `:5439` to the hostname in the connection Server name field.

Just add only the hostname as `some_path.redshift.amazonaws.com` in the server name field for the endpoint

That should solve your problem.